# Are community promotion evaluations ongoing?

Tags: support, community-promotion-ads

I understand that the annual community promotions resets existing ads, but is there then a window for the evaluation?  In other words, if an ad is posted to a `community-ads` tagged question before the next re-evaluation, and adhering to the spec, will it automatically get posted?

For example, if an ad currently has 2 votes and next month or next week it has 7, will it start to be included?

Conversely, if an ad currently has 7 votes and next week it has gone down to 2, will it be removed?

If an ad that doesn't exist gets posted July 16th, adheres to the spec, and gets the requisite 6 votes with 2 hours, will it appear?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, the voting on this year's community promotion ads is ongoing. As long as an ad maintains the requisite number of votes (currently a score of 6 or more), the post will be included in the display ad rotation.

Votes on individual ads do not age off nor are they recalculated monthly or otherwise. When the "Community Promotion Ads" post resets (annually), an entirely new post is created and the previous one is closed. Whatever votes show up on the new ads will determine which are displayed in that current year.

There may be an initial delay until an ad shows up (the votes are checked hourly), but generally speaking, if the current-year's post has a voting score of 6 or more (checked hourly), it will show up in the ad rotation.